# Writing test for exceptions which shows dialogs in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pytest

I have googled so much about this but did not find anything..

I have a custom exception class which invoked a QDialog to show the warning message..Now i am writing test for my application and in the test, i am sending the data which will make the application raise that exception and hence the dialog will appear.

But when i am running the test using `pt.test`, the dialog is appearing and when i close it, this is printed on my console..

```
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE
apptest.py:31: Failed
----------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kapil/mp3wav/mp3wav/application.py", line 62, in <lambda>
    self.connect(self.conversionButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), lambda: self.startConversion())
  File "/home/kapil/mp3wav/mp3wav/application.py", line 79, in startConversion
    self.__convert()
  File "/home/kapil/mp3wav/mp3wav/application.py", line 86, in __convert
    self.checkFile(__OUTFILE)
  File "/home/kapil/mp3wav/mp3wav/application.py", line 105, in checkFile
    raise FileTypeException(fileType, self)
mp3wav.exceptions.fileexception.FileTypeException
```

This is my test file..

```
import pytest
import os
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from mp3wav.application import Mp3WavApp
from mp3wav.exceptions.fileexception import FileTypeException
from mp3wav.exceptions.libraryexception import LibraryException
from mp3wav.exceptions.filenotexistexception import FileNotExistException
from mp3wav.exceptions.samefileexception import SameFileException
from mp3wav.exceptions.overwriteexception import OverWriteException


def windowTest(qtbot):
    testapp = Mp3WavApp()
    testapp.show()
    qtbot.addWidget(testapp)
    assert testapp.isVisible()
    assert testapp.close()

@pytest.mark.qt_no_exception_capture
def fileTypeTest(qtbot, tmpdir):
    testapp = Mp3WavApp()
    qtbot.addWidget(testapp)
    infile = tmpdir.mkdir("files").join("demo.mp3")
    infile.write("something")
    testapp.inputFileLine.setText(str(tmpdir.join("files", "demo.mp3")))
    testapp.outputFileLine.setText(str(tmpdir.join('files')))
    testapp.outputFileLineName.setText('demo.wave')
    with pytest.raises(FileTypeException) :
        qtbot.mouseClick(testapp.conversionButton, Qt.LeftButton)
```

Here is the custom exception

```
import os
import sys
from mp3wav.exceptions.errordialog import ErrorDialog

class FileTypeException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, sid, parent=None):
        super(FileTypeException, self).__init__()
        filetype = "mp3"
        if sid==2:
            filetype = "wav"
        errorMessage = "The Selected file is not "+filetype+\
        "\nSelect the appropriate file"
        if parent:
            dialog = ErrorDialog(parent, errorMessage)
            dialog.show()
            dialog.exec_()
        else:
            print(errorMessage)
```

What i think is that it is failing because the dialog is appearing during the run of my test and i need to close it manually..But i don't know exactly why the test is failing..

Can anyone please guide me to the right path.. It will very much be appreciated..